# How do I diagnose the last shutdown? adb root?

Tags: root-access, logging, nexus-5x, crash-reports

Everything I've read indicates `/proc/last_kmsg` used to be how, however that seems to have changed with Android 6.0 (I'm on 8.1). I've also seen reference to `/sys/fs/pstore/console-ramoops` for Android 6.0+, but I have no file called that. I can't `ls` the directory either, because apparently I don't have root shell with adb.

I've tried `adb bugreport`, but that doesn't seem to contain shutdown logs.
I've tried `adb root`, but I get the message:

```
adbd cannot run as root in production builds
```

I have a Nexus 5x that is rooted, with TWRP and Magisk.

The only other suggestion I've seen is to edit '/system/build.prop' to include the line `ro.debuggable=1`, but I can't access that file either due to a lack of root access.

I've spent a week trying to sort this out. Surely it can't be this hard to find shutdown logs?

Comment: Persistent store doesn't exist on your device because your kernel isn't built with `CONFIG_PSTORE_*` options. Last_kmsg also works if phone isn't manually restarted. Yes, only on `userdebug` and `engineering` builds of ROM, `adbd` can run as root, not on `user` builds. In fact you can't do any reasonable debugging on non-debug ROMs without root access. Btw why are you looking for kernel logs? Are you building some ROM?

Comment: Why are you trying to read the shutdown logs ? 
 
May be there's another method of diagnosis.
 
Have you tried logcat ?